# Model->save function forced bind integer param to varchar column on CentOS 6

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm developing an Laravel App.
and I'm in trouble on inserting data to mysql.

table that i intend to insert,　named 'savetest' like below.

```
id    int(11)
token varchar(40)
tmp   varchar(128)
```

here is a result 'show create table savetest'

```
CREATE TABLE `savetest` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'id',
   `token` varchar(40) NOT NULL COMMENT 'access token',
   `tmp` varchar(128) NOT NULL COMMENT 'tmp',
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=91 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

and model is below

```
class SaveTest extends Eloquent
{
    protected $connection = 'vmspapp';

    protected $table = "savetest";

    // public $timestamps = false;

  /**
   * The name of the "created at" column.
   *
   * @var string
   */
  const CREATED_AT = null;

  /**
   * The name of the "updated at" column.
   *
   * @var string
   */
  const UPDATED_AT = null;
}
```

and code that insert a data, just like this

```
$testee = new SaveTest();
$testee->token = "test";
$testee->tmp = "ok";
$testee->save();
```

after executed code above, inserted data below

```
id : 1
token : test
tmp : 0
```

it seems like a last binded parameter forced converting to Integer value.

More Strange, when i tried these on another environment built on AWS,
insert has succeeded.
and anothoer environment too.

environment succeeded 1 are,

```
ec2 Amazon Linux AMI 2014.09.1 t2-micro
php 5.4.36
```

environment succeeded 2 are,

```
CentOS 5.5
php 5.4.26
```

environment failed are,

```
CentOS 6
php 5.5.20
```

does anyone know why this happen and how solve this?

Comment: Recheck your table and be sure that the tmp column is actually varchar and wasn't somehow changed to int.  Can use `show create sasaki_savetest`

Comment: thx, but i'm sure to create varchar column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently encountered this issue, it was simply the Zend Cache being out of date.